# Yii framework или обычный php?

Tags: framework, php, yii

Здравствуйте, гуру. Недавно узнал о неком волшебном Yii framework (да и вообще о фреймворках на php). Посмотрел, да, вещь хорошая, **но** я не знаю стоит ли уходить с чистого php на него, потому что 2 их я думаю трудноват о выучить (каша в голове будет)... В Yii я делаю приложения немного быстрее, но на php привычней... Вот сижу мучаюсь, помогите с выбором

```
PHP учу уже 1,5 года
```

Comment: @Angus123 на plain php далеко не уедешь. Так или иначе скоро начнёшь писать функции и классы облегчающие жизнь.  
Не проще использовать чужой опыт хождения по граблям?  
Да и опыт работы с фреймворками всегда будет в плюс.

Comment: Просто я хотел бы работать в будущем php программистом, и вот не знаю что для работы подойдет... Если вдруг будет коллективный проект, все пишут на обычном, а ты на Yii...

Comment: @Angus123 откровенная глупость. Как будущему php-программисту вам надо знать не только php, но и хотя бы один популярный php-фреймворк или cms.  
И да, ИМХО, если вся группа пишет БОЛЬШОЙ проект на простом php, то лучше в код не заглядывать без валидола.  
P.s. не путайте понятия: php <> yii

Comment: @Angus123 А php-фреймворк написан на "непростом" php?

Comment: @zhenyab ага, это магия ;)

Comment: > PHP учу уже 1,5 года

и задаете такие вопросы 

> Если вдруг будет коллективный проект, все пишут на обычном, а ты на Yii...

fuck my brain

Comment: ну я поделками на пхп занимаюсь уже лет 7 и не писал ничего на фреймворках :)

Comment: Сначала нужно очень хорошо знать ООP на PHP чтобы приступать к изучению их

Comment: @SverxnovA ООП надо знать. Остальное вторично.

Answer (score 8):

Ну изначально тебе стоит изучать сам язык вне зависимости от того какой фреймворк на php ты будешь юзать.

фреймворк и язык программирования разные вещи.

Учи язык, фрейм поможет создавать приложения просто быстрее.

Comment: Тогда уж не язык, а алгоритмы программирования - но это если уж совсем программистом хочется стать. И опять же, если взять Bit#%x, то можно отметить, что там даже не особо нужно знание мускуля, чтобы писать под него :)

Comment: если взять Bit#%x - то лучше вообще не программировать и даже не смотреть в эту сторону.

Вопрос стоял не про алгориnмы а про фрейм и конкретно php так что ответ именно по вопросу.

Comment: Либо я неправильно понял суть вопроса или он задан некорректно. Дословно: "но я не знаю стоит ли уходить с чистого php на него". А чистый PHP это что? Это процедурный код? Выше я привел Bitrix только потому, что по моему скромному мнению с таким подходом к пониманию PHP можно и на нем писать (фу-фу-фу).

Answer (score 3):

На гуру не претендую, но могу сказать, что yii стоит того что его нужно изучить. Будет взрыв мозга.

Comment: Yii меня очень радует. Но, как сказал @Shrek - сначала нужно изучить PHP, хотя бы основы.

Answer (score 2):

Все верно, используй Yii framework для развертывание проектов, если боишься забыть чистый php, возьми ученика кого нибудь_) обучение других, даст тебе отточенный инструмент, который в любое время будет готов к бою)

Comment: Бред какой-то, чтобы не забыть, брать ученика. Или у Вас очень много времени?

Comment: Для поднятие проф уровня самое то! Повторение - мать учения!

Answer (score 1):

Изучение фреймворков это хорошая практика) Хотябы для личного опыта. В них уже реализованны повседневные задачи, плюс вы застрахованны от ошибок при разработке(не от всех конечно). Вывод изучайте YII)

Comment: > плюс вы застрахованны от ошибок при разработке

по незнанию можно изобретать велосипед, и писать в обход фреймворка )

Comment: **Оффтоп**

> плюс вы застрахованны от ошибок при
> разработке

Документация как бы намекает:

> with: список дочерних связанных
> объектов, которые должны быть
> загружены с самим объектом.
> Неправильное использование данной
> возможности может привести к
> бесконечному циклу.

так что фреймворк не панацея от ошибок

Answer (score 0):

Yii - фреймверк среднего уровня, надо начинать с более простого.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/178833/